# Bad hyperlink on changed map route MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, maproute

I am building a ASP.NET MVC application. In the RouteConfig.cs I am adding MapRoutes as follows:

```
var appModel = new AppModel();
var apps = appModel.GetAppNames();
foreach (var appName in apps)
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "application" + appName,
        url: appName + "/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

When I go to page, for example `http://localhost/appName1/Dashboard` I have a link on my view that points to `http://localhost/appName1/Home/About`.

After that, when I go to another page - `http://localhost/appName2/Dashboard`, my link on my view still points to `http://localhost/appName1/Home/About`(and it should be `http://localhost/appName2/Home/About`). I am building the link with `<a href='@Url.Action("About", "Home")'>about</a>`. How to solve this?

Comment: How are you building the link? (`@Html.ActionLink`, `@Html.RouteLink`, ...?)

Comment: @BradChristie `<a href='@Url.Action("About", "Home")'>about</a>`